# how to generate sentence vector using word2vec?

Tags: python, nlp, word2vec

I want to generate the vectors of the sentence using word2vec techniques. I have developed this code but getting an error.

```
import pandas as pd
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
df = pd.read_csv('after stopwords.csv')
vocab = df['plot']
model = Word2Vec(sentences=vocab, size=100, window=10, min_count=3, workers=4, sg=0)
df['plot'].apply(model.vectorize)
```

Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-9fdf8b202e75> in <module>
      4 vocab = df['plot']
      5 model = Word2Vec(sentences=vocab, size=100, window=10, min_count=3, workers=4, sg=0)
----> 6 df['plot'].apply(model.vectorize)

AttributeError: 'Word2Vec' object has no attribute 'vectorize'
```

Comment: The error clearly specified where the problem is. The `model` variable holds ` an object of word2vec type`. Check the methods and attributes of word2vec class.

Comment: @Priya i am new to gensim could you please help me in this?

Comment: yeah...what is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Priya I have resolved this issue thanks for the precious time.

Answer (score 1):

Thw word2vec algorithm doesn't specify any way to create a single vector for a sentence, nor does the `Word2Vec` model class in Gensim.

One potential way to turn a text (like a sentence) with a bunch of words into a vector, using some set of word-vectors, is to represent the text as the average of all the individual word-vectors. Do you think that's what you want to do?

Separately: your `Word2Vec` model is unlikely to be useful, as your `vocab` variable doesn't look like it's the right format for `Word2Vec` training. The class expects each item in its training data to be a *list* full of *individual words*. That is, it doesn't take texts as strings, but as already-tokenized lists-of-strings.